# Built-in way to convert xml to an ActiveRecord Object in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, api, activerecord

In Rails 3, is there a way to produce an ActiveRecord object from xml in a controller without writing code yourself to explicitly parse it? Say for example, could a controller receive xml like

```
<user>
 <first_name>Bob</first_name>
 <last_name>Smith</last_name>
</user>
```

and have it produce a proper User object similar to User.new(params[:user])? This is for an api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
@user = User.new
@user.from_xml(xml_data)
```

**Update**

On overriding you can do something like this:

```
#user.rb
def from_xml(xml_data)
  book = Book.new
  book.from_xml(extract_xml_from(xml_data))
  self.books << book
  super(xml_data)
  save
  book.save
end
```

Please note that the most important line in the overriding is the `super(xml_data)` which will take care on calling the original `from_xml(xml_data)` of the `ActiveRecord` model.
So you can customize the rest as needed, but this line is neede if you want to get the original functionality as well.
Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Very nice. Although it seems to have an issue if the xml contains nested associations. I get a "Book expected, but got Hash" error for a nested <books><book><title>Camelot</title></book></books>.

Comment: You can try to override the `from_xml` method to get it work with nested associations.

Comment: So is this for books, users *and* books, or what?

Comment: A user with associated books. Dombesz's advice of overriding `from_xml` is certainly a viable solution, though I'm disappointed that Rails doesn't seem to have a standard way to handle associations within the xml.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a gem, xml_active that might help you with this without having to write a lot of code.  You can check it out at https://rubygems.org/gems/xml_active.

To get it to create one object with associations just do the following:

```
book = Book.one_from_xml xml_data
```

You can also get xml_active to create many objects from xml along with associations. There are more features but probably not in the scope of this answer.  You can check them out on the home page for the gem.

UPDATE

xml_active has now been officially retired and development is now focused on data_active (see https://github.com/michael-harrison/data_active) which has the functionality of xml_active but in future releases I will be working to support other formats